# Make isosceles triangle with matchsticks

Tags: geometry, triangles, ceiling-and-floor-functions, pattern-recognition

> Alan is using matchsticks to make isosceles triangles. Isosceles triangles have at least two sides of the same length. How many different single isosceles triangles can he make with B matchsticks, using all the matchsticks each time?

Not sure I understand the answer [here](http://www.jiskha.com/display.cgi?id=1383717181) where $B = 45$ (or 33?):

Why do we have $X+2X=B$? What if B is not divisible by 3?

What I tried:

If it's 3,5,6, Alan can make only 1 isosceles triangle. If it's 7, he can make 2.

Is this something like $\lfloor \frac{x}{3} \rfloor$? Or  $\lfloor \frac{x}{3}+1 \rfloor - 1$?

Comment: BCLC, it is NOT okay to change the title to your question to have the question be something else, to then discard an existing correct answer. This is rude and not up to the standards.

Comment: @vrugtehagel oh sorry and thanks for the info. So I should have asked a new question instead?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't now since I've helped you in the comments, and people are usually glad to help with further related problems if not too big or far from the original question, but you should NEVER change your original post to mean something else.

Comment: @vrugtehagel but I didn't ask if I should. I asked if I should have.

Comment: No, because it was very closely related to the question. My point was, you shouldn't have changed the title of the post.

Comment: @vrugtehagel so what should I have done then if not change or ask new? Suffer with my error by putting myself at your mercy? Why not just let me have asked another question? We still keep our rep (15 for you, 2 for me)

Comment: I don't care about reputation. All I care about is helping people and keeping this site as clean and easy-to-use as possible. If you ask a question, and someone answers, you should not change the intention of the original post, because it will confuse future readers. If you have further questions regarding the post, and they are closely related to your original question, you can ask for clarification in the comments (as you did). If your have further questions that either are too far from the original or too complex to answer in a comment, then consider asking a new question.

Comment: @vrugtehagel thanks but the person might not answer. So what to do please?

Comment: Wait. And if that doesn't work, ask a new question if the sub-question was different enough from the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if we call the number of matches in the base side of the triangle $a$, and the number of matches in the other two sides (which totals to $2b$ for both sides) then we need to find the number of solutions to $a+2b=B$. This is simply the number of numbers you can fill in for $b$, since then $a=B-2b$ follows.

Thus, in general, the number of triangles you can make is $\lfloor\tfrac 12(B-1)\rfloor$, because that's how many $b$'s there are such that $B-2b\geq1$.

As correctly noted, we need to take the triangle inequality $2b>a$ into account. When we try to find the number of $b$'s that do *not* satisfy that property, we look at $2b\leq a$, or $2b\leq B-2b$, in other words, all $b$ less than or equal to $\frac{B}{4}$. Subtract this from $\lfloor\tfrac 12(B-1)\rfloor$ to find the final answer:

$$\lfloor\tfrac 12(B-1)\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{B}{4}\rfloor$$

---

Note that now for $B=45$, we get the correct answer $$\lfloor\tfrac 12(45-1)\rfloor-\lfloor\frac{45}{4}\rfloor=\lfloor22\rfloor - 11=11$$

Comment: You also need to account for the triangle inequality, i.e. $2b>a$.  For example, for $B=45$, is $b=1$, $a=43$ really feasible?

Comment: vrugtehagel, thanks! I think $B=33$ not $45$. Does that clear things up?

Comment: @Aweygan, you're absolutely right, I edited my answer. BCLC: the OP on the forum you linked was right about the answer, when $B=45$, the number of triangles is $11$.

Comment: How to explain this to an 11 year old please?

Comment: Take some matchsticks and show him/her. Visuals really do help understanding concepts, especially with younger children.

Comment: vrugtehagel sorry for the confusion I mean the part with the floor and ceiling. Everything before is 'Thus, in general, the number of triangles you can make ' ?

Comment: You need a decent basis to understand this. First teach him/her what he/she needs to know, then jump into proofs like this. There are proofs that I won't understand no matter how they're explained, simply because I lack the base knowledge required to understand that proof.

Comment: @vrugtehagel thanks ^-^